# How to find max and min value from filtering by ID and Date on a Range

Tags: excel

I have a excel file having Summary and Details records

[image]

[image]

** here is a excel fiddle **
https://ethercalc.org/t42iqg64tj8p

What I need is that on Summary table, **Location 0**, **Location 1** and **Location 2** is calculated.

So I have to lookup into details by **ID** and **Date** and **Location** and get do `MAX(Value) - MIN(Value)`.

So for example if I filter Details by **ID** `1` and **Date** `04/09/2019` by Location 0 and get `Max` Value I should get: **2**

and `Min` Value should get: **1.1**

> ..so result of MAX - MIN should be `0.9`

I have tried `VLOOKUP` and `MAX` with nested `IF` statements but dont know how.

> Any clue

Comment: What version of Excel? You can use `MAXIFS` and `MINIFS` if they are available, otherwise you can recreate using `MAX` and `MIN` + `IF`.

Comment: Excel 365 so Latest

Comment: Then use `MAXIFS` and `MINIFS`.

Comment: But MAXIFS only have option to one match criteria and I need 3 match criteria, ID, Date and Location

Comment: `MAXIFS` can have multiple criteria. Just like `SUMIFS` or `COUNTIFS` (that's why it ends in `S`).

Comment: I tried MAXIFS seems i dont have that funcion :(

Comment: What language is your Excel in?

Comment: How do I check that? Excel uses forumals. Im not using VB script

Comment: I mean is your Excel installation in English, Spanish, German, or some other language?

Comment: Its in English language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `MAXIFS` and `MINIFS` if they are supported in your version of Excel:

```
=MAXIFS(D6:D19,A6:A19,A2,B6:B19,C2,C6:C19,0)-MINIFS(D6:D19,A6:A19,A2,B6:B19,C2,C6:C19,0)
```

Otherwise use the following array formula - enter using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
=MAX(IF(A6:A19=A2,IF(B6:B19=C2,IF(C6:C19=0,D6:D19))))-MIN(IF(A6:A19=A2,IF(B6:B19=C2,IF(C6:C19=0,D6:D19))))
```

Replace the `0`s with `1` and `2` for the other locations.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, is very strange my version of Excel 365 is returnin 0 with the  same formula as you have. Is it possible here to attach the excel file so I can see yours? Im sure is exactly as you and i get 0

Comment: As a google doc - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H7DuXUy1MMbgb4vT_cGjlH8_HOFpA9sreLUr3QRlePA/edit?usp=sharing. Copy/paste to Excel and replace the formula in `D2` with the one from the question. Don't forget to enter the formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.